# How to fix "Error enabling this function: Address exceeds the allowed range" in C

Tags: c, morse-code

I am trying to create a program that converts a letter or number input by the user to morse code which then blinks an LED matching the output. I am getting the "Error enabling this function: Address exceeds the allowed range" message when looking at the debugging and am unsure of how to fix this. What do I need to do?

I've tried looking the problem up and changing the value of the arrays doesn't seem to change the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "msp432.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX 100
#define SIZE 255


void LED_();
void LED_setup();

int main(){

char string[MAX][SIZE];
char destination[MAX] [MAX] [8];
char *input[38]={

                 ".-",   //A
                 "-...", //B
                 "-.-.", //C
                 "-..",  //D
                 ".",    //E
                 "..-.", //F
                 "--.",  //G
                 "....", //H
                 "..",   //I
                 ".---", //J
                 "-.-",  //K
                 ".-..", //L
                 "--",   //M
                 "-.",   //N
                 "---",  //O
                 ".--.", //P
                 "--.-", //Q
                 ".-.",  //R
                 "...",  //S
                 "-",    //T
                 "..-",  //U
                 "...-", //V
                 ".--",  //W
                 "-..-", //X
                 "-.--", //Y
                 "--..", //Z
                 ".----", //1      //numbers begin here
                 "..---", //2
                 "...--", //3
                 "....-", //4
                 ".....", //5
                 "-....", //6
                 "--...", //7
                 "---..", //8
                 "----.", //9
                 "-----", //0
                 "/"     //space

};

char *output[38]= {
                   "A",
                   "B",
                   "C",
                   "D",
                   "E",
                   "F",
                   "G",
                   "H",
                   "I",
                   "J",
                   "K",
                   "L",
                   "M",
                   "N",
                   "O",
                   "P",
                   "Q",
                   "R",
                   "S",
                   "T",
                   "U",
                   "V",
                   "W",
                   "X",
                   "Y",
                   "Z",
                   "0",
                   "1",
                   "2",
                   "3",
                   "4",
                   "5",
                   "6",
                   "7",
                   "8",
                   "9",
                   "/"
};

char *code, *separator = " ";

int i;
int c;
int j;
int x;
int m[MAX];

printf("Enter the number of cases:");

scanf("%d", &x);
getchar();

for(i = 0; i < x; i++){

    printf("Case#%d: ", i+1);
    gets(string[i]);

}

for(i =0; i < x; i++){
    for(code = strtok(string[i], separator); code != NULL; code = strtok(NULL, separator)){  
        strcpy(destination[i][j++], code);                                                   
    }                                                                                        

    m[i] = j;  
}

for (i = 0; i < x; i++){

    printf("Case#%d: ", i+1);

    for(j = 0; j < m[i]; j++){
        for(c = 0; c < 37; c++){
            if(strcmp(destination[i][j], input[c]) == 0){  
                printf("%s", output[c]);                   
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        LED_setup();
        LED_();

    }

}
return 0;
}

void LED_(char* mval){   

char* a;

for (a = mval; a != NULL; a++){
    if (*a == '.')
    {
        P4->OUT |= 0x01;    //LED On
        _delay_cycles(500); //Delay 0.5 second
        P4->OUT &= ~0x01;   //LED Off
    }
    else if (*a == '-')
    {
        P4->OUT |= 0x01;     //LED On
        _delay_cycles(1000); //Delay 1 second
        P4->OUT &= ~0x01;    //LED Off
    }
    else
    {
        _delay_cycles(750);  //delay of 3/4 second
    }
}

}

void LED_setup(){

P6->DIR |= 0x01;
P6->OUT &= ~0x01;

}
```

Comment: You call `LED_()` without a parameter, but the function is declared like this: `void LED_(char* mval)`. Compile with all warnings enabled, and treat the warnings as errors.

Comment: Please tell us what your hardware is. It seems the address bus is too small and you re exceeding addressable program memory.

Comment: On this line `strcpy(destination[i][j++], code);` `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm using code composer and it isn't giving any more errors even after changing the settings. How would you recommend declaring the function? I can't seem to get it to declare properly even after fiddling? 
Also, j is defined before being used. What needs to be done to initialize it?
 I am using a TI MSP432 board as the processor per request from my professors.

Comment: @Jay declare change `void LED_();` to `void LED_(char* mval);` and provide an appropriate parameter to when you call `LED_`. Also initialize the variable `j` before using it (probably a `j = 0;` is missing somewhere). Uninitialized local variables have an indetermined value.

Comment: @Jabberwocky So I went through and did those changes but Code Composer didn't want to run it. Using another person's laptop we found it ran all the way down to the third "for" loop. It seems to get stuck on that loop?

Comment: Calling `LED_()` without a parameter is simply wrong. It will lead to _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). You should declare functions without parameters with void: `void LED_setup();` -> `void LED_setup(void);` and declare `LED_`correctly: `void LED_();` -> `void LED_(char* mval);`. Then your program won't compile unless you call `LED_` with an appropriate argument.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting the "Error enabling this function: Address exceeds the allowed range" message …

You might exceed a translation limit. Especially the array `char destination[MAX] [MAX] [8]` has (at least, if `char` is a byte) 80000 bytes, which is more than the minimum required for an implementation conforming to the C Standard:

> — 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)

You don't need such a big array, since you don't need to convert all input strings first and only after that output the converted `destination` to the LED - instead you could convert and output one string at a time. Try rearranging your program that way, using just `char destination[SIZE][6]` (the maximum code length is 5).

Another thing you can try is to move the big arrays `string` and `destination` to global scope - local variables might be more restricted than globals by the implementation.